# What statue did Bolivia give, and where is it located?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, landmarks, gifts

From [*Babyhood*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0071QS4L8) by Paul Reiser:

> Every place I looked I saw a great place to be somebody's parent.
>
> "I could walk into *that* 7-Eleven and buy my kid a soda … I could play ball in *that* park and teach my kid how to hit a jump shot … I could pass *that* statue and explain to my kid why Bolivia sent us a guy on a horse … " It all seemed nothing but good.

Any idea what statue he was referring to? (Or is it a fictional one?)  I'd be keen to visit it, given the opportunity.

([Reiser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Reiser) is from New York, but I don't know where he was living when he wrote the book.)

Comment: Sorry but how is this related to travel?

Comment: @rlesko, would you be okay with "A _Reader's Digest_ article on New York City mentioned a statue of Gustav Mahler. Does anyone know where it is?"? If so, can you articulate the difference between that and this?

Comment: @rlesko lots of people read about things and then want to go see them.  I specifically visited the statue of a dog in South Africa, the star of the book "Jock of the Bushveld"(!).

Comment: @msh210 I guess his point is, you've not made it a travel question. That sounds pedantic, but if you could reword it, it'd definitely be a better fit.  I'm about to edit it now, let me know if you don't like my changes, I'll try to keep it intact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The one he is probably referring to was actually presented by Venezuela - [The Equestrian Monument](http://www.nycgovparks.org/parks/centralpark/monuments/132) of [Simon Bolivar](http://www.centralparknyc.org/visit/things-to-see/south-end/simon-bolivar.html), liberator of Bolivia, Panama, Colombia, Ecuador, Peru, and Venezuela from Spanish rule.

[image: photo of the monument]

This statue is at the entrance to Central Park at the north end of Sixth Avenue - The Avenue Of The Americas - so it fits the context of the story well.

Photo from nycgovparks.org